# Is there such a thing as a use case relationship diagram?

Tags: uml, diagram

I know about use case diagrams.  But is there something called a use case relationship diagram?  How is it different?

Comment: Do you actually own a book on UML? If not, I suggest you get one.

Comment: @solairaja: Don't see any problems with this question. Don't be so aggressive.

Answer (score 2):

A use case diagram contains one use case. In RUP, there's a use case domain model that displays the relationship between the different use cases. In a use case, you can also include and extend other use cases, which also displays a certain relationship between use cases.

RUP stands for Rational Unified Process, it's a widely used development process, especially in a bit more formal organisations. It makes heavy use of UML diagrams. http://nl.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_Unified_Process

Answer (score 1):

You must be thinking of Use Case relationships. Quoting [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Use_case_diagram):

> **Use Case Relationships**
>
> Three relationships among use cases
>   are used often in practice.
>
> **Include**
>
> In one form of interaction, a given
>   use case may include another. "Include
>   is a Directed Relationship between two
>   use cases, implying that the behavior
>   of the included use case is inserted
>   into the behavior of the including use
>   case"[1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Use_case_diagram).
>
> The first use case often depends on
>   the outcome of the included use case.
>   This is useful for extracting truly
>   common behaviors from multiple use
>   cases into a single description. The
>   notation is a dashed arrow from the
>   including to the included use case,
>   with the label "«include»". This usage
>   resembles a macro expansion where the
>   included use case behavior is placed
>   inline in the base use case behavior.
>   There are no parameters or return
>   values. To specify the location in a
>   flow of events in which the base use
>   case includes the behavior of another,
>   you simply write include followed by
>   the name of use case you want to
>   include, as in the following flow for
>   track order.
>
> **Extend**
>
> In another form of interaction, a
>   given use case (the extension) may
>   extend another. This relationship
>   indicates that the behavior of the
>   extension use case may be inserted in
>   the extended use case under some
>   conditions[1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Use_case_diagram). The notation is a
>   dashed arrow from the extension to the
>   extended use case, with the label
>   "«extend»". Notes or constraints may
>   be associated with this relationship
>   to illustrate the conditions under
>   which this behaviour will be executed.
>
> Modelers use the «extend» relationship
>   to indicate use cases that are
>   "optional" to the base use case.
>   Depending on the modeler's approach
>   "optional" may mean "potentially not
>   executed with the base use case" or it
>   may mean "not required to achieve the
>   base use case goal."

Comment: So is that a different kind of diagram?

Comment: It's not a diagram. It's a concept within a diagram

Comment: (there is no such thing as a use case relationship diagram)

Answer (score 1):

Here's more information about showing relationships between use cases: **UML Use Case Diagrams: Reference** at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd409427%28VS.100%29.aspx

> **Include**: An including use case calls or invokes the included one. Inclusion is used to show how 
>   a use case breaks into smaller steps. The included use case is at the arrowhead end.
>
> **Extend**: An extending use case adds goals and steps to the extended use case. The extensions 
>   operate only under certain conditions. The extended use case is at the arrowhead end.

[Include and Extend relationships on a use case diagram http://i.msdn.microsoft.com/Dd409427.UML_UCOvStructure(en-us,VS.100).png](http://i.msdn.microsoft.com/Dd409427.UML_UCOvStructure(en-us,VS.100).png)